# Does tasting salt break one's fast?

Tags: ramadan, sawm

In my place, I have seen people tasting salt during fasting. When asked, they responded saying that we aren't eating so should be fine. Is it really fine or does it break the fast?

Comment: AFAIK women are allowed to taste the food they cook while fasting (without swallowing or eating it) just by the tip of the tongue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, **it is permissible for women or even men to taste food with tip of tongue while fasting, but it should not be much and should not read throat, and person should spit the remaining of food.**

Most scholars say **it is makrooh to taste food without a reason**, like when wife know husband will get angry if food does not taste right. Or it is person's duty to chk taste of something. Or any situation like that. And should avoid tasting foods just without any reason, like just to check how it taste for curiosity.

The main reference for this common view on this issue is this fatwa of ibn e abbas

> Sahih Bukhari, Vol. No. 3, in the Book of Fasting, Chapter No. 25, it
>   says  "**Ibn Abbas he narrated that tasting food from the pots or meals
>   it does not break the fast**.

While some say this hadees is mua'llaq, but this is the common and correct view among most of the ulamas.

For more details see [this](https://islamqa.info/en/49658) or [this](http://www.islamweb.net/eramadan/articles/140685/tasting-food-during-ramadan)

### Allah knows best